# Making curved path appear parallel in relation to a TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a diagram which looks like this:

[image]

I have horizontally aligned nodes `b` and `c` with regards to their centers, but this causes an issue with the curved path `z` due to the fact it is no longer symmetrical.

How can I make the ends of the path `z` to be parallel to one another and the label align with node `a`, like in the diagram below, while still keeping `b` and `c` centrally aligned?

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2cm, align=center,
block/.style={rectangle,draw, thick,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=10mm},
paths/.style={->, very thick, >=stealth'},
curve/.style={<->, thick, >=stealth', bend left=270, looseness=2, distance = 60mm},
]

%Draw, place, and label variables
\node [block] (a) {a};
\node [block] (b) [above right=of a] {bbbbbbbbbb};
\node [block] (c) [below= 4cm of b.south, anchor = north] {ccc};
%\node [block] (c) [below right= of a] {ccc}; % ideal curved path between b and c here, but block not centered

% Draw paths and label them
\draw [paths] (a) to node {x} (b);
\draw [paths] (a) to node [swap] {y} (c);
\draw [curve] (b) to node [swap,midway] {z} (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example first places the node `z` for "z" to the left of node `a` to get "z" at the same base line as "a". Then the curve is split into two parts, from node `b.west` to `z.east` and `z.east` to `c.west`. The components `.west` and `.east` ensure the correct starting and ending points. The start and end angles of the curve parts are specified by options `in` and `out` for path operator `to`. This requires library `topaths`:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc,topaths}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2cm, align=center,
  block/.style={rectangle,draw, thick,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=10mm},
  paths/.style={->, very thick, >=stealth'},
  curve/.style={<->, thick, >=stealth'},
]

%Draw, place, and label variables
\node [block] (a) {a};
\node [block] (b) [above right=of a] {bbbbbbbbbb};
\node [block] (c) [below= 4cm of b.south, anchor = north] {ccc};
%\node [block] (c) [below right= of a] {ccc}; % ideal curved path between b
%and c here, but block not centered

% Draw paths and label them
\draw [paths] (a) to node {x} (b);
\draw [paths] (a) to node [swap] {y} (c);
\node [xshift=-3em, anchor=base east] (z) at (a.base west) {z};
\draw [curve] (b.west) to[out=180, in=90] (z.east)
                  to[out=-90, in=180] (c.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

And a variant, where the straight connections `(a) -- (b)` and `(a) -- (c)` are connected at the corners. In this case it might look better.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc,topaths}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2cm, align=center,
  block/.style={rectangle,draw, thick,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=10mm},
  paths/.style={->, very thick, >=stealth'},
  curve/.style={<->, thick, >=stealth'},
]

%Draw, place, and label variables
\node [block] (a) {a};
\node [block] (b) [above right=of a] {bbbbbbbbbb};
\node [block] (c) [below= 4cm of b.south, anchor = north] {ccc};
%\node [block] (c) [below right= of a] {ccc}; % ideal curved path between b
%and c here, but block not centered

% Draw paths and label them
\draw [
  paths,
  shorten <=-.7\pgflinewidth,
] (a.north east) to node {x} (b.south west);
\draw [
  paths,
  shorten <=-.7\pgflinewidth,
] (a.south east) to node [swap] {y} (c.north west);
\node [xshift=-3em, anchor=base east] (z) at (a.base west) {z};
\draw [curve] (b.west) to[out=180, in=90] (z.east)
                  to[out=-90, in=180] (c.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result variant corners]

Comment: Thanks for adding the more aesthetically pleasing version!